# Sending mail when services stops

Tags: cron, email, services, mail

How can I let Ubuntu sent me a mail when a certain service stops?

I've mail() running so I can check it by a cronjob and sent a mail when a certain service has stopped. How?

For instance:

```
sudo service apache2 status
 * apache2 is not running
```

Using a grep() at the message? Do I have to check it every minute. Not a good idea regarding performance of the server I suppose?

Anybody suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

```
  if ps ax | grep -v grep | grep apache2 > /dev/null
    then
        exit 0
    else
        echo "apache2 is not running!" | mail -s "Apache2 is down"
        sudo service apache2 start

    fi
```

and about the running the bash script, it depands on you how often you wanna check it, 
I think , every 15 minutes will be enough to check or every hour.

that will be the crontab command if you want to check every 15 minutes:

```
*/15 * * * * /tmp/checkservice.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

this will check the service every 15 minutes and if the service is not running then it will send you an email,
you can also add auto start code in else part if you want this task also to be automatized.